# Storing Results of queries into one table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have multiple different queries and I want to store their results into one table. Results of this queries may have different number of rows and columns.

e.g.
I have three queries:

Q1. `select name,id from employee;`  (Result has 2 columns and 2 rows)

Q2. `select salary from emp_table`     (Result has 1 column and 4 rows)

Q3. `select country_name,Country_id,count(id) from players group by country_name,Country_id` (result has 3 columns and 3 rows)

Now, I want to store these results into one table which has structure like :

```
Query_ID | col1  | col2 | col3
-------------------------------
```

In this table query_id is unique id to queries like A1,A2,A3...

When queries have less than three columns as result, remaining column should be filled with null (for first query col3 should be null and for second query col2 and col 3 should be null).

desired output:

```
Query_ID | col1   | col2 | col3
----------
A1       | John   | 1356 | NULL
A1       | Mathew | 1667 | NULL
A2       | 1500   | NULL | NULL
A2       | 2000   | NULL | NULL
A2       | 3000   | NULL | NULL
A2       | 3500   | NULL | NULL
A3       | US     | 010  | 25
A3       | UK     | 012  | 26
A3       | GER    | 016  | 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alias to your fields to have a uniform result set for your different queries.

For Q1 `select name as col1,id as col2, '' as col3 from employee;`

For Q2 `select salary as col1, '' as col2, '' as col3 from emp_table`

For Q3 `select country_name as col1,Country_id as col2,count(id) as col3 from players group by country_name,Country_id`

Then you can use your insert statement to save those queries. example:

`INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3)
select name as col1,id as col2, '' as col3 from employee;`

Then you can use any of the above queries as you want to your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You Use `Union All`

```
SELECT  'A1' AS Query_ID, name AS Col1, id AS Col2, '' AS Col3 
FROM employee

UNION ALL

SELECT 'A2' AS Query_ID, salary AS Col1, '' AS Col2, '' AS Col3
FROM emp_table

UNION ALL

SELECT 'A2' AS Query_ID, country_name AS Col1, Country_id AS Col2, count(id) AS Col3
FROM players 
GROUP BY country_name, Country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into new_table (query_id,col1,col2,col3)
select 'A1' as QUERY_ID,name as col1,id as col2,'' as col3 from employee
union all
select 'A2' AS QUERY_ID,salary as col1,'' as col2,'' as col3 from emp_table
union all
select 'A3' AS QUERY_ID,country_name,Country_id,count(id) from players group by country_name,Country_id;
```

Make sure the data types of the column that you are fetching are compatible. Suppose name column is varchar and salary that you are fetching is number that this will fail.